Typescipt Union discrimination not showing an error
There is an API which accepts two kind of inputs. There are some not-necessary fields, but if one of them is present, they must all be set.
I wanted to make a TS-type of the input, but the following code doesn't show an error, even thought I think it should:
type InputBase = {
  testAttribute: string;
};
type InputWithFlag = InputBase & { flag: 2; flagInfo: string };
type Input = InputBase | InputWithFlag;

const testInput: Input = {
  testAttribute: "test",
  flag: 2,
};

Since flag in not undefined, TS should infere that flagInfo may not be undefined or am I missing something? I consulted this page https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions but couldn't find an answer.
When adding a function which uses these types which utilizes in-operator-narrowing (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing), there is also no error shown, and it logs "undefined" (which is correct JS, but shouldn't happen given the type definition).
const test = (input: Input) => {
    if("flag" in input){
        console.log(input.flagInfo)
    }
}

test(testInput)

Here is the TS-playground link:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBASQHZQK5gEIEMDO8C8cA3qHHGDDmAIJhgBOAlgEbowBccVTSA5gNygAvoPDR4yNGADqjMAAsAYgBssvOIUnpseOADJicAGarenAEz9jp5EYD2nboz5wRoSLEQp0Gr1J3wAD5+6LIKKmqioADGdkhU5JRgWmCcKb4kIGQUVLQMLGycAEQ5YEUANKTWahaVIG4gMXEJpb4AFM5Sad5gAJQaAHzEVWSMRm1FJmpFcM6zPb2ZZMvL9DBgqPRIcLHxdsowAHTKdrwdPYdTvLZ2vSOu92sbWzvN+0cnZ0VIdtW8RXd6qB3Ek2qUUr0gA
What am I doing wrong?

flag is not a discriminant because InputBase does not know one way or the other about whether flag is present.  You probably want this version instead, where you make Input a union of InputWithoutFlag and InputWithFlag, where InputWithoutFlag says that flag is either missing or undefined.  And you don't want in narrowing with that version. See linked q/a for more information.
